EKS- pod stuck in containerCreating state when attached to 2 claims with RWX accessmode and efs storage class
I have pod deployed in EKS which has 2 PVCs attached, below is yaml snipped for the same
  - name: dev1-rwx-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: dev1-rwx-volume-pvc
  - name: dev2-rwx-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: dev1-rwx-volume-pvc

Below is the PVCs snippet
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: pv-dev

I have EFS file system created and have below storage class pointing to that
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
parameters:
  directoryPerms: "700"
  fileSystemId: fs-id
  provisioningMode: efs-ap
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer

Issue: If i remove one volume from the pod it works fine but with 2 RWX volumes it gets stuck in containerCreating stage with no log or events. Is it an issue with using 2 PVCs with aws EFS storage class in same pods, which i dont think so but need to confirm or if I am missing anything here ?
